# how to add dynamic button to dynamically created linear layout in android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, textview, android-linearlayout

After creating a dynamic linear layout with two dynamic TextView 1.textView and 2.textView_dynamic, i have written a onclick for textView_dynamic to add a dynamic button in dynamically created linear layout. after a click view is added but button is not visible it shows empty space.

Here is the code:-

Code:-

```
// Parent1 layout
LinearLayout parent1Layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater2 = getLayoutInflater();
View view2;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
// Add the text layout to the parent layout
    view2 = layoutInflater2.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parent1Layout,false);

    //In order to get the view we have to use the new view with text_layout in  it
    TextView textView = (TextView)view2.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText("Row 2" + i);

    //Add the text view to the parent layout
    parent1Layout.addView(textView,i);

    final LinearLayout dynamic = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    dynamic.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dynamic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    // Layout inflater
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater1 = getLayoutInflater();

    final View view1;
    view1 = layoutInflater1.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, dynamic, false);

    TextView textView_dynamic = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView_dynamic.setText("Linear dynamic new dynamic " + i);

    dynamic.addView(textView_dynamic);

    parent1Layout.addView(dynamic, i);

    textView_dynamic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Button button2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
      button2.setText("Dynamic Add");
      button2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      dynamic.addView(button2);
      j++;

     }});
}
```

Comment: What is at line: 120 ?

Comment: at line 120:- button2.setText("But_Lin "+ j);

Comment: So is button_dynamic in the text_layout? You may post your layout xmls too.

Comment: where you have initialized `j` ? what is its initial value ?

Comment: int j=0 is initialized a global variable

Comment: @oberflansch  as you asked button_dynamic layout, i have changed it to dynamic button, now i am not getting nullpointer exception. view is added but button is not visible it shows empty space.